# Adding null values to an array

Tags: php, arrays, reflection, null

I have the this method:

```
public function search($searchKey=null, $summary=null, $title=null, $authors=null, $paginationPage=0) { 
    ... 
}
```

And I'm trying to retrieve all parameters with this:

```
$Class = new Search();

// Get parameters
$ReflectionMethod = new \ReflectionMethod($Class, "search");
try {
    foreach($ReflectionMethod->getParameters() AS $Parameter) {
        if(array_key_exists($Parameter->name, $this->params)) {
            $parameters[$Parameter->name] = $this->params[$Parameter->name];
    } elseif($Parameter->isDefaultValueAvailable()) {
        $paramaters[$Parameter->name] = $Parameter->getDefaultValue();
    } else {
            ...
    }
} catch(\Exception $e) {
        ...
}
    // Call function
return call_user_func_array(array($Class, "search"), $parameters);
```

My `$this->params` has this content:

```
array
  'paginationPage' => int 2
  'id' => int 30
  'searchKey' => string 'test' (length=4)
```

Because $summary, $title and $authors are not present, they will get their default value which is `null`. When assigning a null value to an argument, it will be skipped which results in a $parameters array that looks like this:

```
array
  'searchKey' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'paginationPage' => int 2
```

Which result in a method call like:

```
public function search('test', 2, null, null, 0) { 
        ... 
}
```

While it should be:

```
public function search('test', null, null, null, 2) { 
        ... 
}
```

Hopefully you see the problem. How can I make sure those null values are also put into my `$parameters` array. Adding an invalid value is not possible, because it is user input, so that can be basically everything.

**Edit**

In the example above the method `search` is hardcoded. But one of the simplified things is that `search` is actually a variable and because of that `search` can be anything. This means that I don't know what the parameters of the method are and I can't predefine them before the foreach loop. The solution of predefining the parameters is actually exactly what this code should be doing.

Comment: What do you mean with *When assigning a null value to an array it will be skipped* ? When I add `null` to an array, the key is present in the array: http://codepad.org/zIl0wArH

Comment: I think this was a typo in the question. I've changed it to *When assigning a null value to an argument*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my... It was just a simple typo:

```
...
} elseif($Parameter->isDefaultValueAvailable()) {
    $paramaters[$Parameter->name] = $Parameter->getDefaultValue();
} else {
...
```

Shame on me!

Answer (score 7):

How about pre-initializing `$parameters` before entering the `foreach` loop:

```
$parameters = array(
    $searchKey => null,
    $summary => null,
    $title => null,
    $authors => null,
    $paginationPage => 0
);
```